# ¿Cómo soluciono "deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'"?

Tags: arduino

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto con arduino sobre un control de acceso con clave ya tengo el código y al momento de compilar me sale este error:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
>   [-Wwrite-strings]

```
Password password = Password("2802A");  //Define la contraseña
```

---

Aquí el codigo:

```
#include <Password.h>
#include <Keypad.h> //Incluimos la libreria Keypad
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>  //Incluimos la libreria LiquidCrystal

Password password  =  Password ("2802A");  //Definimos el Password // de aquí viene el error
int dlugosc = 5;                        //Largo del Password

LiquidCrystal lcd(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5); //Definimos los pines del LCD

int buzzer = 10; //Creamos las Variables de salida
int ledRed = 11; 
int ledGreen = 12;

int ilosc; //Numero de Clicks

const byte ROWS = 4; // Cuatro Filas
const byte COLS = 4; // Cuatro Columnas

// Definimos el Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = { 9,8,7,6 };// Conectar los keypads ROW1, ROW2, ROW3 y ROW4 a esos Pines de Arduino.
byte colPins[COLS] = { 5,4,3,2, };// Conectar los keypads COL1, COL2, COL3 y COL4 a esos Pines de Arduino.

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup()
```

Ahí ya sigue lo que se ejecutará.

Aquí completo:
https://mega.nz/#!VVxA0aqA!HIdVizXnzyBUyfFCZeCGDZd7Q8MIwM1-bL2DSJYrODU

Comment: Te recomendaria que agregaras tu codigo, para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Así? te agradecería mucho si me ayudas a solucionarlo; primero van las librerias y ahi esto

Comment: Hola @ArialdoFernandez, ¿mi respuesta solucionó tu problema?

Comment: LA mejor form aes declarar el arreglo fijo algo como esto.
char message[27] = "Ok Reporte +569 XXXX YYYY";

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que esa cadena de caracteres es `const char*` y parece que esa función pide un [`char*` (ver código)](https://github.com/phrac/arduino/blob/master/tutorials/Password.h#L51), por lo que una solución podría ser:

```
/* Definimos la contraseña */
char* clave = "2802A";
Password password = Password(clave);
```

De esta manera los tipos de datos coinciden.

Otra forma sería, por ejemplo:

```
/* Definimos la contraseña */
char[] clave = "2802A";
Password password = Password(clave);
```

Comment: El problema es que asignar una constante de cadena como "2802A" a un char * provoca el mismo error de deprecated conversion, porque "2802A" es un const char *, no un char *.

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo correcto es así:

```
char CLAVE[6] = "2802A";
Password password = Password(CLAVE);
```